# Positive Distinct Summands in Python

Tags: python, algorithm, greedy

This Code is giving wrong output for `n=2` and it is very slow.

How Can i make this code for finding as many positive distinct summands more efficient?

**TASK**- Represent a given positive integer `n` as a sum of as many pairwise
distinct positive integers as possible.

**OUTPUT**: First Contains an integer `k`.Second Line Contains `k` positive distinct positive summands that sum up to `n`.

`Sample Input:`

`8`

`Output:`

`3`

`1 2 5`

```
n=int(input())
p=[]
i=1
while(i<=n):
      if (n-i) not in p:
          p.append(i)
      n-=i
      i+=1
print(len(p))
print(*p)
```

Answer (score 9):

You can solve the problem analytically. If the number you're trying to reach is `N`, then the answer will always be

```
1+2+3+ ... +n + r = N
```

where `n` is the largest possible number such that `n < r`. For example, take `N=8`, and consider the possible values of `n`

```
n   sum(1..n)  r
0       0      8
1       1      7
2     1+2=3    5
3    1+2+3=6   2    // too high, n is not less than r
```

Thus, when `N` is 8, `n` is 2 and `r` is 5, giving an answer of 1+2+5.

So the question becomes, given the value of `N`, how can we compute `n`. The first step is to note that the sum of 1 thru `n` is given by the equation

```
1+2+3+ ... +n = n(n+1)/2
```

Plug that into the first equation

```
n(n+1)/2 + r = N
```

Using the fact that `n < r`, we can rewrite this as

```
n(n+1)/2 + n < N
```

[image]

And that's the answer that you need to implement. For example, if `N` is 2, then the formula says `n < 1` which means that `n` is 0 and `r` is 2. If `N` is 8, then `n < 2.77`, which means that `n` is 2 and `r` is 5.

Answer (score 2):

One way to find the sequence is to have two starting points: N and m, where N is the number we are trying to reach and m starts at 1.

Next, we increase m by 1, add it to the sequence and reduce N. The solution is reached by reducing N by m and stopping when N <= m *2.

For example, if the number that we are trying to reach is 3

```
N = 3
```

Then,

```
s={} #  array to store pairwise distinct positive integers
k = 3 # k = N at the beginning 
m = 1  #  always starts at 1 
m*2 = 2
```

since

```
 k is not <= m*2
```

we add **m** to the array, subtract **m** from **k**, add **1** to **m** and repeat the same process again.

```
s = {1}
k = k - m = 3 - 1 = 2
m = 1 + m = 1 + 1 = 2
```

Now,

```
m*2 = 4
```

since

```
 k <= m*2
```

We add **k** to our array and we are done.

```
 s = {1, 2}
```

Here is the code in python that does the same thing.

```
def optimal_summands(n):

 summands = [] # array to store pairwise distinct positive integers
 k = n # marked the upper part
 m = 1 # marked the lower part

 if n == 2 or n == 1:
     summands.append(n)
 else:
     for i in range(1,k):
         if k <= 2*m:
             summands.append(k)
             break
         else:
             summands.append(m)
             k = k - m
             m = m + 1

 return summands
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if your code has other flaws but I can see that there are test cases similar to n=2 that will make this fail (I believe n=9 will, for example). Try `if ((n-i) not in p and n-i != i)`. You fail n=2 because it sees that i=1 is not in p, yet you are just about to put it in.

Comment: Thanks and i need to make it fast too.Is there any way to decrease its running time.

Comment: Is it ever possible that (n-i) < i but (n-i) not in p? Off the top of my head, I don't think so. So you should be able to save time by checking (n-i) < i (which is a very cheap operation) instead of (n-i) not in p (which I believe gets more expensive as p gets larger).